# selenium browser makes me do captcha multiple times

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha, captcha

**My Problem:**

- I'm using selenium to order something on a website.
- I have to complete a captcha form before my order can be processed.
- On a normal browser I would only need to solve the captcha form once,
  but when I'm using selenium I have to complete about 4 captcha's
  before my order can be processed.

***What I've tried***

- I tried to use my default profile for selenium, to make it seem as if my selenium browser is almost the same as my normal browser, but it still wouldn't work.

  ```
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\coderoftheday\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
  browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=options)
  ```

**Please note me or a any human would solving the captcha on a selenium browser, so its not the computer solving the captcha**

Answer (score 0):

That's because they detect you as a bot. Extra captias run when they think the user is automating the browser.